# Geotools: Render a GridCoverage2D to a heat map

Tags: heatmap, geotools

I'm new to use geotools. Now I need to generate a heat map showing the data density.

I found a Kernel density estimation process from here: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOT-4175, and so far it gives me a heatmap surface over a set of irregular data points as a GridCoverage2D.

My question is, how can I display it in a heat map fashion? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: transform the GridCoverage2D to a geotiff and view it? You can select the output for the heatmap wps process as either tiff or arcgrid